# How can I find a specific button on an Instagram page? What I thought would work isn't

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, findelement

I am trying to click the save info button you get when you first log in to an Instagram account. I can't because I keep getting ElementNotFound errors.

I tried this code and it gave this error:

```
chrome.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "_acan _acap _acas").click()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\interaction_bot_base.py", line 1255, in process_application_commands
    await app_command.invoke(interaction)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\disnake\ext\commands\slash_core.py", line 739, in invoke
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
disnake.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"._acan _acap _acas"}
```

Comment: I also don't know why it's recognizing my search method as css_selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce that. But I see the problem in you approach. `By.CLASS_NAME` is searching by one class name but here you are trying to search by three names. `class` attribute in `html` store one or more class names. If there are more than one class name in the `class` attribute, class names are separated with spaces. So `"_acan _acap _acas"` is not a class name but a list of class names. And I guess none of them is unique for the page.
So, to be able to find the element using all three class names you can do the following:

```
chrome.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@class="_acan _acap _acas"]').click()
```